Does code require wrapped porch posts to be treated against rot?
I hired a contractor to replace some columns on my front porch as part of a larger job.  In our verbal conversations, I used the phrase "wrapped 4x4 posts" numerous times.  My assumption was that this would be a treated 4x4 post wrapped in treated 1x's.
After the columns were built we discovered that the porch area needed to be jacked up.  We removed the trim at the bottom with the intention of jacking up, adding support, and reattaching the trim.
When we removed the trim we discovered that they had used two untreated 2x4s.  They did rest them on a post base so there is technically no ground contact but I still think this is a bad idea.
I've complained to the contractor but they are digging in their heels stating there is no code violation here since there is no wood to ground contact.
Even if this isn't strictly against code, I think it is a bad idea and intend to redo it but I would love to be able to cite code to this contractor if there is an applicable one.  Can anyone give me some guidance on this?

We don't know the code where you live, because we don't know where you live...

I've built many porch columns in regulated jurisdictions, whether wrapped with cedar plywood, brick or stone, or just pine boards. They were never required to use pressure-treated lumber when they were wrapped. Just as with a typical exterior wall, it's the job of whatever "siding" is applied to handle weather. The interior framing is assumed to be protected.
No, code isn't likely to call for pressure-treated lumber on the interior of a fully wrapped column. Your assumption was faulty, especially if you didn't specifically request that.
